# Swift viewWillAppear redirect

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, nsuserdefaults

I'm using "viewWillAppear" to check UserDefaults.standard if i have data on the defaults i want redirect to Dashboard View and pass out of Login.

When i Log In correctly the app redirect normally but not in viewWillAppear in case of have data.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if defaults.string(forKey: "username") != nil {
       print("Exist")
       print(defaults.string(forKey: "username")!)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Dashboard")
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

And i get this error con debug.

```
2016-11-04 17:44:32.130024 RHiOS[1155:278240] Warning: Attempt to present <RHiOS.MenuViewController: 0x100f0d480> on <RHiOS.ViewController: 0x100e0b880> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

How can i redirect to Dash in case of have data? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot present a ViewController in `viewWillAppear`. Simply put this code in `viewDidAppear` and it should fix your problem.

When the view is not visible, it's not in the window hierarchy as the error mentioned. You could also create a segue in your storyboard and call `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` instead.

Comment: But, how can i make that before the Login shows check, if the UserData exist dont show the Login just show the Dashboard, but if the UserData is empty show the Login, need a parents of aViewController instance?

Comment: you cannot use presentations to solve this problem. it's ok to show the main screen and then animate into a login screen, but if you want to avoid this you can set the window.rootViewController in the AppDelegate before anything is even presented to the user

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to present anything when the view hasn't appeared yet, so you either have to move your code into **viewDidAppear** or prevent this view from showing in the first place and redirect directly to the dashboard from a parent view controller that presents either the dashboard or login screen depending on whether or not you have data.